# curl_multi_exec how to execute it on several ip adresses and get response headers

Tags: php, http, curl, libcurl

Hello i have made a curl test on an ip and i could get the response infos( times, response code,...)
this time i want to make it work on several ip's in the same time. I found that could be possible with curl_multi_exec, and i found this code:

```
         // create both cURL resources
        $ch1 = curl_init();
        $ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net/");
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//create the multiple cURL handle
        $mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch1);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch2);

        $running = null;
//execute the handles
        do {
            curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
        } while ($running > 0);


//close the handles
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
        curl_multi_close($mh);
```

But i only get the hole content of the last url entered (CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net/")
and besides, i want the informations abouts the request and response( in curl i used `($infos = curl_getinfo($curl);)`

Comment: got help with any answer ? consider marking it as correct for future help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need [PHP cURL Class With Multi-Threading](http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading)
Get it here http://pastebin.com/vBgYDzVu or here http://semlabs.co.uk/assets/files/curl.zip

**Ex:**

```
    include "curl.php";

    $curl = new CURL();
    $optsA = array( CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
 CURLOPT_HEADER => 0 );
    $optsB = array( CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_HEADER => 0 );
    $curl->addSession( "http://siteA.com/scriptA.php", $optsA );
    $curl->addSession( "http://siteB.com/scriptB.php", $optsB );
    $curl->addSession( "http://siteC.com/scriptC.php", $opts );
    $curl->addSession( "http://siteD.com/scriptD.php", $opts );
    $curlresult = $curl->exec();
    $curl->clear();

    $siteA = $curlresult[0]
    $siteB = $curlresult[1]
    $siteC = $curlresult[2]
    $siteD = $curlresult[3]
```

Comment: the libcurl multi interface that is using, is *NOT* using multi-threading. It is doing parallel simultaneous downloads in a single thread.

And btw, the code above is also using the curl multi interface so I don't think this answer helps very much...

Comment: @Daniel-Stenberg : Parallel simultaneous requests is what's needed in this case, if the author of the class named it wrong you need to talk with him, thanks for pointing that tho. http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading

Comment: People are wrong all over the Internet, that's not a good reason to repeat them here...

Comment: it seems that you're taking this way to serious, completely disregarding the user question.